# MsBuild: Item: Remove with absolute path

Tags: msbuild

This comes from a Shared project:

```
<Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MyFile1" />
```

Let's say it's equivalent to

```
<Content Include="c:\MyProject\MyFile1" />
```

This comes from a normal project:

```
<Content Include="MyFile2" />
```

One is an absolute path, the other is a relative one.
Which makes issues when trying to `Remove` them, because eg the one with the relative path can't be `Remove`-d with its absolute path.
It seems `Remove` does string matching and not Path matching.
Maybe I have to type into `Remove` the exact same string as it was `Include`-ed?

I can remove these files with:

```
<Content Remove="MyFile2" />
<Content Remove="c:\MyProject\MyFile1" />
```

I can't remove them with:

```
<Content Remove="c:\MyProject\MyFile2" />
<Content Remove="MyFile1" />
```

Is there a way to tell MsBuild these are paths and `Remove` them always by absolute path?

Answer (score 2):

Items have a set of metadata - see [MSBuild well-known item metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2022).

`%(Identity)` will be the string that was used for the item in the `Include`. But if the Item is a file that exists, then `%(FullPath)` will have a value.

e.g. Your example items are:

| Identity | FullPath |
| --- | --- |
| c:\MyProject\MyFile1 | c:\MyProject\MyFile1 |
| MyFile2 | c:\MyProject\MyFile2 |

You need to use `Identity` for the `Remove` but you can create a new ItemGroup that is a subset of `Content` by testing the `FullPath` and then use that ItemGroup as the value of your `Remove`.

An example might be

```
<Target Name="Test">
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToRemove Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(FullPath)' == 'c:\MyProject\MyFile1' or '%(FullPath)' == 'c:\MyProject\MyFile2'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="@(FilesToRemove)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Target>
```

The `FilesToRemove` ItemGroup is using task batching and must be within a `Target`.

Another example of the same approach but testing the file extension:

```
<Target Name="Test">
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToRemove Include="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.js'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="@(FilesToRemove)" MatchOnMetadata="Extension" />
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Target>
```

The `Remove` attribute accepts wildcards but

```
<Content Remove="**\*.js" />
```

won't work because it will not match items added without using a wildcard.

Comment: The problem is I would like to use path wildcard `**\*.js`. So this does not work: `<Content Remove="@(Content)" Condition=" '%(FullPath)' == '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.js' " />`. Btw, I can achieve the result with 2 `<Content Remove=...` steps, using 1 for the ProjectDir-relative path, and 1 with full path. That works, but it is easy to forget to write both. The question was for a better solution.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more clear. And your example in your comment helps. Thanks. If the point of the exercise is to remove .js files, note that the `Remove` attribute does accept a wildcard, e.g. `<Content Remove="*.js" />`